# Is there any usage of relation data base design for mobile app which is don't have the db?

Tags: php, android, rdbms

1. An android app runs with out the help of databases means, is there any necessity to create the relational database design?
2. If I am using php as a back end means they have tables, databases etc., so for they only create the relational database design wright?
3. Relational database design for either database only or  it will be used for design the app modules also.

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear Android has its own local database named SQLite - a lite version of SQL. It depends on you to whether use it or not . If you need to store data in persistent storage you can use it . Various other type of database u can use with the help of  libraries like SnappyDB , Realm etc .
SQLite too uses tables , rows and columns to store data just like SQL but the data types are limited and some other functionalities of SQL missing .

When u are using database from backend , you just need to create php scripts (or RESTful web services ) to connect with your database .

It depends on use case whether local database and backend database have same relational design .

Comment: okay thanks for your update and response, i know how to use the sqlite db in android. The thing is i want , relational db design needed for if the application must run with the db only wright.  And if the application no need db means we wont considered about the relational design wright